# Not share cookies between subdomains

Tags: session, cookies, browser, server

I have two websites that shared the same server. The websites and the server sharen the same domain:

```
              app.example.com       admin.example.com
                      \                  /
                       \                /
                        \              /
                        api.example.com
```

When a user login into `app.example.com` the cookies of this site are also available in `admin.example.com`. I want to know if is possible don't share the cookies between the subdomains. That the cookies of each subdomain be isolated.

I have tried to set the domain of the cookie to one of the subdomains, but the browser rejects the cookies:

```
Set-Cookie: domain=app.example.com
```

I want to know how can I handle this case, have different websites connected to the same server but that don't share the cookies that they use to access the server.

This is the configuration of the cookies that I am using:

```
Set-Cookie: 
    name=key; 
    domain=example.com; 
    Path=/; Expires=Fri, 03 Jun 2033 03:15:40 GMT; 
    HttpOnly; 
    Secure; 
    SameSite=Strict
```